# Ignore `libseccomp package not found` error in go.mod file

Tags: macos, go

I've been experimenting with [libseccomp-golang](https://github.com/seccomp/libseccomp-golang) and I've encountered the following problem in the `go.mod` file:

`pkg-config: exec: "pkg-config": executable file not found in $PATH`

This is an expected error because `pkg-config` is not installed. However, when I install it via `brew` I receive the following error:

```
# pkg-config --cflags  -- libseccomp
Package libseccomp was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libseccomp.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'libseccomp' found
pkg-config: exit status 1
```

I know that `libseccomp` is a linux-specific package and I do not have a linux distribution installed. However, I would really like to ignore the error in the `go.mod` file, because everything works as expected when I build the project in a docker container. Is there any way to ignore this error?

Comment: This has nothing to do with the go.mod file, the error happens during compilation. If you have Linux specific dependencies, make sure they are only compiled with Linux build constraints

Comment: Yeah I've encountered that as well while doing some more research. Is it possible to let VSCode know to "ignore" this error? Because I only compile the project in a docker container which has the ubuntu image.

Comment: Did you try build constraints like I mentioned?

Comment: What do you mean? I never build anything on my machine related to this project.

Comment: If you never build anything, then you would never see this error. If you are editing it on your machine in vscode, it's using various plugins and tools to analyze and build the source. Some tools may need the target GOOS and GOARCH, but cross compiling cgo is a another problem entirely.

Comment: Ok I see. I've tried to change the GOOS and GOARCH already, but without luck. So it seems there is no other way around to get rid of the error in vscode?

Comment: Again, have you tried adding build constraints? I don't know what the result will be in vscode, I don't use it, but preventing the files from attempting to compile on the wrong architecture seems like a good first step.